# 3 IntelliSense: declaration is incompatible with "<error-type> Airport::getDetails(std::string)"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, intellisense, incompatibletypeerror

recieving this error

i know its something to do with declaration and definition mis-match but i cant seem to put my finger on it.

Any help would be appreciated :)

```
IntelliSense: declaration is incompatible with "<error-type> 
Airport::getDetails(std::string)" (declared at line 16 of "z:\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\oo_cw\oo_cw\Airport.h") 
z:\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\oo_cw\oo_cw\airport.cpp    50  22  OO_CW
```

Heres my header file and cpp file

header

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"


class Airport
{
public:
Airport();
~Airport(void);
//Modifiers
void setName(string);
void addConnection(string,double,double);
void setTax(double);
//Accessors
string getName();
connections getDetails(string) const ;
double getTax();

private:
string name;
Vector<connections> destinations;
double tax;
};
```

cpp

```
#include "Airport.h"
#include <string>
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
using namespace std;

struct connections {
    string destName;
    double price;
    double time;
};

Airport::Airport()
{
name = "";
tax = 0.0;

};




Airport::~Airport(void)
{
};

void Airport::setName(string airportName){
Airport::name = airportName;
}
void Airport::setTax(double airportTax){
tax = airportTax;
}

void Airport::addConnection(string conName, double conPrice, double conTime){
connections newConnection;
newConnection.destName = conName;
newConnection.price = conPrice;
newConnection.time = conTime;
destinations.push_back(newConnection);
}

string Airport::getName(){
return name;
}

double Airport::getTax(){
return tax;
}

connections Airport::getDetails(string reqName) const {
for(int i =0;i<destinations.size();i++){
    if(destinations[i].destName==reqName){
        return destinations[i];
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You have to put `connections` definition above class `Airport` definition in the header file.
2. Your function `Airport::getDetails()` must return something for the trivial case, where `destinations.size() == 0`, (see code below).
3. Is there a particular reason not to use `std::vector` in the place of `Vector`?

---

```
connections Airport::getDetails(string reqName) const {
  for (int i = 0; i<destinations.size(); i++){
    if (destinations[i].destName == reqName){
      return destinations[i];
    }
  }
  return connections{"", 0.0, 0.0};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't declaring `connections` before you use it in "Airport.h".